# Laravel: Target [Lcobucci\JWT\Parser] is not instantiable

Tags: php, laravel

Hey I am having an issue on my prod website trying to log in with Laravel passport.  It says my Lcobucci JWT Parser is not instantiable.  It works for me locally but not on my remote.

How can I resolve this?

**Error:**

```
exception: "Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException"
file: "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php"
line: 1038
message: "Target [Lcobucci\JWT\Parser] is not instantiable while building [Laravel\Passport\PersonalAccessTokenFactory]."
trace: [,…]
```

**Login Controller Method:**

```
public function login(Request $request) {

        $login = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required:string',
            'password' => 'required:string'
        ]);

        if(filter_var($request->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            //user sent their email 
            Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password]);
        } else {
            //they sent their username instead 
            Auth::attempt(['username' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password]);
        }

        if(!Auth::check()) {
            return response([
                'status' => 'fail',
                'message' => 'Invalid credentials'
            ]);
        }

        $accessToken = Auth::user()
            ->createToken('authToken')
            ->accessToken;
        
        return response([
            'status' => 'success',
            'user' => new User_Resource(Auth::user()),
            'access_token' => $accessToken 
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Try removing the `vendor` folder and running `composer install` again

Comment: @Donkarnash It did not work.

Comment: Which version of the parser are you running?

Comment: @El_Vanja thanks for your response im using `"lcobucci/jwt": "^4.0",`

Comment: If you downgrade it to 3.4, does it work then? Also, make sure both your environments are running the same version.

Comment: Interesting, I've just run into this issue after running a composer update today

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I encountered the same issue as well, in your project composer.json add "lcobucci/jwt": "3.3.3" and execute composer update.
I found this solution on: https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/1381.

Comment: Worked thank! ( seems like problem with updated package version)

Comment: @SunilKumar They also just released v10.1.0 with support for JWT v3.4 which works fine now. Cheers!

Comment: posted 4 hours ago,  what a coincidence! Thank you

Comment: @GamsBasallo Is this a recent issue because I am not seeing much support for this anywhere, and more questions about it.

Comment: @Eddsters Yeah it is, because "lcobucci/jwt" just upgraded to 3.4 with a lot of breaking changes. I found this out on an issue on the laravel-passport github page.I think all should be fine from now on since they just released v10.1 quickly to support JWT v3.4.

Comment: @GamsBasallo what makes me curious is why lcobucci/jwt was never included in the composerjson when installing passport, i never had that dependency and it was working before, but now you have to manually add it.

Comment: @Eddsters The laravel-passport package ships that dependency by default and you can check it on vendor\laravel\passport\composer.json, it was then updated to use ^3.14 | ^4.0 by default which was not yet compatible and resulted with a lot of breaking changes.

Comment: I get this error

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires lcobucci/jwt 3.3.3 -> satisfiable by lcobucci/jwt[3.3.3].
    - lcobucci/jwt 3.3.3 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - laravel/passport[v10.1.0, ..., 10.x-dev] require lcobucci/jwt ^3.4|^4.0 -> found lcobucci/jwt[3.4.0, ..., 3.4.x-dev, 4.0.0-alpha1, ..., 4.2.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (3.3.3).
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/passport ^10.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/passport[v10.1.0, ..., 10.x-dev].

Answer (score 13):

**Laravel : "8" and Lcobucci\JWT : "^3.4"**

Solution:

```
use Lcobucci\JWT\Encoding\JoseEncoder;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Token\Parser;
.
.
...
public function GetTokenId(Request $request)
{
  // Get the Access_Token from the request
  $Token = $request->bearerToken();
  // Parse the Access_Token to get the claims from them the jti(Json Token Id)
  $TokenId = (new Parser(new JoseEncoder()))->parse($token)->claims()
   ->all()['jti'];
  return $tokenId;
}
```

Comment: A perfect solution to get TokenId! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

if anyone still getting this error that's because `$verifiedIdToken->getClaim('sub')` has been deprecated in 3.4 and removed in 4.0.
use `$verifiedIdToken->claims()->get('sub')` this insted.

Comment: https://lcobucci-jwt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/upgrading/#support-for-multiple-audiences